# How to get the same GUI using tkinter not Qt Designer

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to write a GUI like in the picture
[image]

and I did it, but with the help of Qt Designer.
However, after converting this code to Python, I don't understand the syntax, so I wanted to create something like this with a tkinter whose syntax is easier for me.
However, the only thing I managed to write in tkinker was just this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import shutil

root = Tk()

root.geometry("307x470")  

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Label/ComboBox Frame", padx=15, pady=15)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=1, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=1, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=3, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=5, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text=".").grid(row=6, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="e").grid(row=6, column=4, padx=1, pady=1)

my_combo_d = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=['01', "02"], width=6)
my_combo_d.current()
my_combo_d.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

my_combo_msc = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["01", "02"], width=6)
my_combo_msc.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
my_combo_msc.current()

my_combo_rok = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["2021", "2022", "2023"], width=6)
my_combo_rok.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)
my_combo_rok.current()

godz_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["01", "02", "03"], width=6)
godz_combo.current()
godz_combo.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

min_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["00", "01", "02"], width=6)
min_combo.current()
min_combo.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)

ener_combo_1 = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["1", "2"], width=6)
ener_combo_1.current()
ener_combo_1.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

ener_combo_2 = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], width=6)
ener_combo_2.current()
ener_combo_2.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)

ener_combo_3 = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], width=6)
ener_combo_3.current()
ener_combo_3.grid(row=6, column=5, padx=1, pady=1)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root,text="Button Frame", padx=15, pady=15)

frame2.grid(row=1, column=0)

b2 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)
b3 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)
b4 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)
b5 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)

b2.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
b3.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
b4.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
b5.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Can anyone help me / suggest how to get the GUI as close as possible to that like in the picture???

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I just changed the number of columns to get things to line up better.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import shutil

root = Tk()

root.geometry("250x470")  

frame1 = LabelFrame(root, text="Label/ComboBox Frame", padx=15, pady=15)
frame1.grid(row=0, column=0)

Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=1, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=1, column=5, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=3, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="Label:", width=8).grid(row=5, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text=".").grid(row=6, column=2, padx=1, pady=1)
Label(frame1, text="e").grid(row=6, column=4, padx=1, pady=1)

my_combo_d = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=['01', "02"], width=6)
my_combo_d.current()
my_combo_d.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

my_combo_msc = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["01", "02"], width=6)
my_combo_msc.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)
my_combo_msc.current()

my_combo_rok = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["2021", "2022", "2023"], width=6)
my_combo_rok.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=1, pady=1)
my_combo_rok.current()

godz_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["01", "02", "03"], width=6)
godz_combo.current()
godz_combo.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

min_combo = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["00", "01", "02"], width=6)
min_combo.current()
min_combo.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)

ener_combo_1 = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["1", "2"], width=6)
ener_combo_1.current()
ener_combo_1.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=1, pady=1)

ener_combo_2 = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], width=6)
ener_combo_2.current()
ener_combo_2.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=1, pady=1)

ener_combo_3 = ttk.Combobox(frame1, values=["3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], width=6)
ener_combo_3.current()
ener_combo_3.grid(row=6, column=5, padx=1, pady=1)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root,text="Button Frame", padx=15, pady=15)

frame2.grid(row=1, column=0)

b2 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)
b3 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)
b4 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)
b5 = Button(frame2, text="Button", padx=15, pady=15, width=20, height=1)

b2.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
b3.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
b4.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
b5.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need tanks for the help :)